# SFML 2 drawing does not work when connected with OGRE

Tags: c++, sfml, ogre, ogre3d

I am currently working on connecting OGRE and SFML.
SFML should be used for 2D drawing, network stuff and input. 
OGRE is for the 3d Graphics.

Currently the whole thing is on Linux.

What works: Connecting OGRE and SFML. First I create a SFML Render Window, then I grab the handle of this window and give it to the OGRE Render WIndow while creating it. I can use the SFML Events now. Did not test the Network stuff, but I am sure this will work too.

What does not work: Drawing in the SFML window.

Case 1: SFML and OGRE are not connected. OGRE does not have the SFML window handle and has its own window. SFML still can't draw in its own window! The main loop executes a maximum of 3 times and then just stops. Nothing more happens. A few seconds later (about 20 or so) I get a Memory Access violation and the program ends.

Case 2: SFML and OGRE are connected. A similar thing happens: The main loop executes exectly 53 times, nothing gets drawn and then the program stops with the terminal message "aborted" (actually its "Abgebrochen", because it's in German)

The strange behaviour also happens, when I let SFML draw into a sf::RenderTexture instead of the sfml_window.

Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <OGRE/Ogre.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

if(argc == 1)
    return -1;


// start with "1" and you get 1 window, start with "0" and you get two
bool together = atoi(argv[1]);  


// create the SFML window
sf::RenderWindow sfml_window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "test");
sf::WindowHandle sfml_system_handle = sfml_window.getSystemHandle();
sfml_window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
std::cout<<sfml_system_handle<<std::endl;


// init ogre
Ogre::Root * ogre_root = new Ogre::Root("", "", "");
std::vector<Ogre::String> plugins;
plugins.push_back("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0/RenderSystem_GL");

for(auto p : plugins)
{
    ogre_root->loadPlugin(p);
}

const Ogre::RenderSystemList& render_systems = ogre_root->getAvailableRenderers();

if(render_systems.size() == 0)
{
    std::cerr<<"no rendersystem found"<<std::endl;
    return -1;

}

Ogre::RenderSystem * render_system = render_systems[0];
ogre_root->setRenderSystem(render_system);

ogre_root->initialise( false, "", "");



// create the ogre window
Ogre::RenderWindow * ogre_window= NULL;
{
    Ogre::NameValuePairList parameters;
    parameters["FSAA"] = "0";
    parameters["vsync"] = "true";

    // if started with 1, connect the windows
    if(together) parameters["externalWindowHandle"] = std::to_string(sfml_system_handle);
    ogre_window = ogre_root->createRenderWindow("ogre window", 800, 600, false, &parameters);
}


// ogre stuff
Ogre::SceneManager * scene = ogre_root->createSceneManager(Ogre::ST_GENERIC, "Scene");
Ogre::SceneNode * root_node = scene->getRootSceneNode();
Ogre::Camera * cam = scene->createCamera("Cam");
Ogre::SceneNode * cam_node = root_node->createChildSceneNode("cam_node");
cam_node->attachObject(cam);

Ogre::Viewport * vp = ogre_window->addViewport(cam);
vp->setAutoUpdated(false);
vp->setBackgroundColour(Ogre::ColourValue(0, 1, 1));

ogre_window->setAutoUpdated(false);
ogre_root->clearEventTimes();

//sfml image loading
sf::Texture ring;
std::cout<<"ring loading: "<<ring.loadFromFile("ring.png")<<std::endl;

sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(ring);


// main loop
int counter = 0;
while(!ogre_window->isClosed() && sfml_window.isOpen())
{
    std::cout<<counter<<std::endl;
    counter++;
    std::cout<<"a"<<std::endl;

    // sfml events
    sf::Event event;
    while(sfml_window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            sfml_window.close();
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"b"<<std::endl;


    std::cout<<"c"<<std::endl;
    ogre_root->renderOneFrame();


    std::cout<<"d"<<std::endl;



    // here the strange behaviour happens
    // if this line (draw) isn't present, everything works
    sfml_window.pushGLStates();
    sfml_window.draw(sprite);
    sfml_window.popGLStates();


    vp->update();
    std::cout<<"e"<<std::endl;
    sfml_window.display();

    // only needs to be done for separated windows
    // sfml display updates otherwise, both use double buffering
    if(!together) ogre_window->update(true);
}
return 0;
}
```

Help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: I added the pushGLStates(); and popGLStates(); commands, forgot those earlier!

Comment: You know that OGRE bundles its own GUI system, right?

Comment: yes, but SFML has far more powerful 2D capabilities. Using OGRE for the 2D stuff would be very inconvenient because there is just too much 2D stuff for OGREs functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer really, but too long for a comment:

```
ogre_window = ogre_root->createRenderWindow("ogre window", 800, 600, false, &parameters);
```

Are you sure that it's okay to pass the address of an object you destroy the very next line here with `&parameters`?

Comment: Yes, this is ok. The values of the parameters get set in the createRenderWindow function, the list "parameters" is not used after that.

Comment: @nvoigt Ogre uses a pointer here because the parameter is optional (`nullptr` can be used).

Comment: @feider ok, then just ignore this :)